# Applications of Zorn’s lemma that aren’t chain-complete/directed-complete?

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, posets

Zorn’s Lemma applies to posets in which *every chain has an upper bound*.  However, in all applications I know, the poset is also evidently *chain-complete* — chains have *least* upper bounds.  A few classic such applications:

- AC, using a poset of “partial choice functions”
- the Well-Ordering Principle, using a poset of “partial well-orderings” (ordered by end-extension, not simply $\subseteq$)
- Hahn–Banach, using a poset of “partial functionals defined on subspaces”
- extension of filters to ultrafilters, using a poset of filters.

**Are there any natural applications of Zorn’s Lemma where the poset isn’t chain-complete, or where chain-completeness is less obvious than existence of upper bounds?**

(Indeed, all examples I know are equally obviously *directed-complete*.  Under AC, this is equivalent to chain-complete, but constructively, directed-completeness is stronger.  For those wondering why I’m caring about use of AC while considering Zorn’s Lemma, note that constructively, ZL does *not* imply AC — this is shown in John Bell’s very nice analysis *Zorn's lemma and complete Boolean algebras in intuitionistic type theories*, JSL 1997, https://doi.org/10.2307/2275642.  His surprising (to me) insight is that ZL itself doesn’t imply LEM or AC — most applications, including the classical proof of ZL=>AC, use LEM for the final step “a maximal partial object must be total”.)

Comment: I for one would be interested just in some natural examples of posets which have upper bounds for chains but not least upper bounds (or less obviously so), even if there's no particular application of Zorn's lemma in such a poset.

Comment: Can we extend any given partial order in which every chain has an upper bound to one where every chain has a least upper bound? I would want to add new nodes to serve as the least upper bound of any chain lacking a least upper bound. But I'm not sure whether this argument would inadvertantly use LEM (since frankly I can never tell whether I am inadvertantly using LEM or not—it is a core part of my mathematical thinking).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins You can always Ind-complete. That is, embed $P$ into $Ind(P)$, the poset of downward-closed, upwards-directed subsets of $P$, ordered by inclusion. The poset $Ind(P)$ has least upper bounds for chains, and more generally (but equivalently in ZFC) for directed sets, and is universal with this property. This doesn't require anything more than $P$ being a poset. Now I'm realizing you were probably aware of this and asking about whether this is still true in less than ZFC... for that I suspect the answer is _yes_ but I don't really know...

Comment: @TimCampion: The answer is yes — Ind-completion, constructed exactly as you describe, is the “free dcpo on a poset” in IHOL (i.e. the logic of an elementary topos), if I’m not mistaken.  So it doesn’t rely on any kind of choice or excluded middle.

Comment: Thanks for the Bell reference.  Similarly, Todd Wilson gave
*An intuitionistic version of Zermelo's proof that every choice set can be well-ordered*
 in JSL 66 (2001) 1121--6, doi 10.2307/2695096. Here "well ordered" has the classical definition, so Zermelo's proof has three parts: a formulation of AC, an intuitionistic proof and finally a use of EM.

Answer (score 29):

On the one hand, one might expect that there can be no fully satisfactory example of the phenomenon, in light of the observations mentioned in the comments, namely, that every partial order fulfilling the Zorn's lemma hypothesis can be extended to one in which also every chain has a least upper bound. In effect, one adds nodes to play the roles of those least upper bounds.

The point is that instance of the phenomenon that someone might present can immediately be criticized as unnatural on the grounds that it is incomplete — by forming the completion, we could have chosen an equivalent but better version of the poset, one achieving exactly the same maximal elements, but in which every chain has a least upper bound.

In this sense, the question is fundamentally concerned with  whether there are natural partial orders in which every chain is bounded but for which the least upper bound property fails. Indeed there are, and I shall mention several.

Let me begin by observing that every application of Zorn is equivalently made with an order not having the LUB property.

**Duplication orders.** Take any partial $\mathbb{P}$ and consider the duplication order $\mathbb{P}^*$, in which every element has been duplicated, replaced with two or more clones that are incomparable to each other but ordered with respect to the other elements according to the original order. Every chain in $\mathbb{P}^*$ has an upper bound, if this was true for $\mathbb{P}$, but now there are no least upper bounds for chains not having a largest element, since any of the clones works equally well. The duplication construction is often used for various purposes in mathematics, and this example shows furthermore that every application of Zorn's lemma can be turned into an example of the requested incomplete phenomenon.

But let me also mention several other examples of naturally occuring partial orders in which every chain has an upper bound, but many chains do not have least upper bounds.

**Hausdorff order.** The Hausdorff order of almost inclusion on subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a natural order where every chain has an upper bound, but many chains do not have least upper bounds.

Namely, the *almost-inclusion* relation $A\subseteq^*B$ for subsets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ holds when all but finitely many elements of $A$ are in $B$. One can take equivalence classes with respect to the almost equal relation $A=^*B$, and induce the order on the quotient.

Every chain has an upper bound in its union, but nontrivial countable chains never have least upper bounds, as Hausdorff proved. So this is a natural order where every chain has an upper bound, but many chains do not have least upper bounds.

**Turing degrees and the exact pair phenomenon.** Another type of partial example occurs with the Turing degrees. Every countable chain in the Turing degrees has an upper bound, simply by encoding the whole chain, but no nontrivial countable chain has a least upper bound in light of the [exact pair phenomenon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21991/does-the-exact-pair-phenomenon-for-partial-orders-occur-in-your-area-of-mathemat), by which every increasing countable chain admits (diverse, nonunique) pairs above, such that any point below both is below something in the chain.

[image]

If one were simply to add a node atop the whole structure, then every chain would have an upper bound, but no nontrivial countable chains would have least upper bounds, providing another example. But see this related question, [Does every countable set of Turing degrees have an upper bound, without AC?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/390597/1946) So the Turing degrees are an interesting case in the absence of AC.

**Mod(T).** Consider the class of models of $T$, a first-order theory. This is naturally ordered by the submodel relation, but the property that unions of chains of models of $T$ is still a model of $T$ is equivalent to having an $\forall\exists$ axiomatization. Such kinds of theories are quite common, because with $\forall\exists$ assertions the theory can express certain basic closure properties. But some theories $T$ do not admit such an axiomatization, and in this case, the union of a chain of models of $T$ will not generally be a model of $T$, but by compactness there will always be upper bounds. For example, if $T$ is the theory of a dense linear order with a largest element, then every chain is contained in a model of $T$, but we will often have a choice in placing a new largest element.

**Surreals.** The class of surreal numbers have the property that every set of surreals is bounded, but no set of surreal numbers has a least upper bound or greatest lower bound, except by containing a largest or least element already. The reason is that for any set $A\subset\text{No}$ with no largest element and any upper bound $A<b$, there will be smaller upper bounds $A<c<b$ added at the next available stage after all the elements of $A$ and $b$.

**Conway games.** More generally, the Conway games generally provide a nonlinear order with the same property. The Conway games admit a natural order (see [this article](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-s05/www/lecture-notes/comb-games-notes.pdf)), and while every set of games is bounded, chains do not generally have least upper bounds.

The last few examples are proper class examples, and they only exhibit the every-chain-is-bounded property for set-sized chains. That feature is not sufficient to produce maximal elements via Zorn — for example, every set of ordinals is bounded, but there is no largest ordinal. Nor are there maximal surreal numbers nor maximal Conway games.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure whether one needs AC to prove that every countable chain in the Turing degrees has an upper bound. You seem to have to pick the representing sets for each degree in the chain, and this seems to use countable AC. Every countable chain in the pre-order has an upper bound, but there are choice issues when passing to the quotient. And a similar issue arises in the almost-inclusion order quotient.

Comment: The almost-inclusion poset (where we remove the top element corresponding to $\mathbb N$ itself and more generally to any cofinite subset of $\mathbb N$) has me confused. By Hausdorff's result and Zorn's lemma, there should be a maximal element of this poset. But it seems to me that by symmetry this implies that every countably infinite, co-countable subset of $\mathbb N$ is maximal in this poset, which sounds wrong. Is it possible that this poset has upper bounds for $\omega$-chains but not all chains, so that Zorn's lemma doesn't apply to it?

Comment: @TimCampion The full order has a largest element, $\mathbb{N}$, so every chain trivially has an upper bound. Some uncountable chains converge to that bound, however, and they have no co-infinite bound. Thus, if you remove the largest element, then those chains would no longer have upper bounds, yes.

Comment: I see, I was mistaken in thinking that you were talking about the poset with the top element removed. So in some sense it's one of the "trivial" examples you discuss. I'm trying to think of a way to formulate the condition that a poset have "nontrivial" upper bounds for chains but I think I'm failing. I think another example, though, would be at least the standard construction of an Aronszajn tree, if I recall how it goes correctly.

Comment: @SamHopkins In ZFC, there are uncountable chains with a least upper bound. For example, any maximal chain will have $\mathbb{N}$ as a least upper bound, and it converges in that sense.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, unfortunately all my examples are trivial in that sense. Oh, well.

Comment: Aronszajn trees are never chain-complete. Indeed, no branching $\omega_1$ tree can be chain complete, since it would have to have continuum many nodes on level $\omega$.

Comment: This is very vague and speculative, but I wonder if there is some reasonable partial order on countable graphs with the Rado graph being the unique maximum, where you could use Zorn's lemma to prove its existence...

Comment: @SamHopkins Well, the countable random graph is universal for countable graphs, so we could consider the countable graphs under the embedded induced subgraph relation. Every chain would have an upper bound, because there is a universal graph. But I think there wouldn't be least upper bounds, since there are strict subgraphs that are isomorphic to the whole thing. This is something like the Hausdorff order situation.

Comment: But one should consider the pre-order quotient, since the embedding order itself is not anti-symmetric. And then things get tricky without AC, just as in my first comment above.

Comment: Here's a proposal: to rule out trivial examples, one should look for posets $P$ which have upper bounds for chains such that $cf(P) = card(P)$.

Comment: @TimCampion The order of countably infinitely many side-by-side copies of the rational unit interval has that property.

Answer (score 4):

I hope to both answer the question, and at the say time (in Peter's words) "strengthen the (circumstantial) evidence that any examples must be very rare/obscure".  I won't attempt to avoid AC or LEM.

A natural class of **nonexamples** are algebras (in the universal algebra sense) whose operations have finite arity.  The union of a chain of algebras is also an algebra, and this is a least upper bound in the poset of algebras under inclusion.  So it is extremely unlikely that you would see Zorn's lemma used in such an algebraic setting without also seeing the chain-complete condition.

However, a natural class of **examples** are algebras with operations of infinite (fixed) arity.

At the risk of making the example feel contrived, but for the sake of simplicity and concreteness, consider the class $X$ of algebras defined via a single $\omega$-ary operation $x$ subject to no relations.

**Claim**:  Given any nonempty set $S$, there is a "free" $X$-algebra satisfying no relations except the identity relations, defined on a set containing $S$.

*Proof 1*: By transfinite recursion we build up new elements.  At the base case, just start with $S_0=S$.  At successor steps, let $S_{\alpha+1}$ be the set where we append to $S_{\alpha}$ all "formal terms" of the form $x(\underline{s})$ where $\underline{s}$ is an $\omega$-sequence from $S_{\alpha}$.  Finally, at limits, take the union of the previous steps.  Check that this process stabilizes at the first uncountable ordinal.$\square$

*Proof 2*: Let $P$ be the poset of triples $(T_1,T_2,y)$, where $T_2\supseteq T_1\supseteq S$ are sets, and $y$ is a function $y\colon T_1^{(\omega)}\to T_2$ (interpreted as defining $x$ on part of $T_2$), subject to allowing no nontrivial relations.  We order this poset by saying $(T_1,T_2,y)\leq (T_1',T_2',y')$ when $T_1\subseteq T_1'$, $T_2\subseteq T_2'$, and $y$ is a restriction of $y'$.

This poset does *not* have chain completeness on some countable chains.  It does have upper bounds of we also allow $T_1=T_2=V$ (however, to avoid issues with proper classes of chains, we can take $T_1$ and $T_2$ to be elements of some universe [in the Grothendiek sense], or equal that universe.)  Apply the general version of Zorn's lemma.$\square$

Note: To see that the poset in the previous proof is not chain complete, consider the following example.  Let the sets $S_{\alpha}$ be the sets from proof 1.  Let $x_{\alpha}\colon S_{\alpha}^{(\omega)}\to S_{\alpha+1}$ be the map sending a sequence $\underline{s}$ to the formal term $x(\underline{s})$.

Consider the initial *countable* chain $(S_0,S_1,x_0)<(S_1,S_2,x_1)<\ldots$.  Any upper bound $(T_1,T_2,y)$ on this chain must have $T_1\supseteq S_{\omega}:=\bigcup_{n<\omega}S_n$.  After restricting $y$ to $S_{\omega}^{(\omega)}$, and replacing $T_2$ by the union of $T_1$ and the image of this restricted map, we may as well assume $T_1=S_{\omega}$.

However, $\bigcup_{n<\omega} x_n$ is only a partial function on $S_{\omega}^{(\omega)}$, and there are multiple distinct ways to extend that partial function to a total function.  So there is no *least* upper bound on the given chain.  (There are *minimal* upper bounds though, each looking essentially just like $(S_{\omega},S_{\omega+1},x_{\omega})$.)

There are aspects of this example that can be generalized to make it less trivial and less contrived, but I hope it gives at least one example of the sort of thing you were looking for.

**Edited to add another example not needing any proper classes**:  Let $U$ be any set (finite or infinite).  Let $P$ be the collection of all $X$-algebra structures (whether free or not) on $U$.  We can make $P$ into a poset by the usual subalgebra relation.  This poset is chain complete (which takes a little work), but does not have least upper bounds on any chains of countable cofinality.

Comment: I am a bit confused. $P$ is not a set. Or do you work with Universes?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You can use universes.  I was thinking of $P$ as a proper class (and considered only set-sized chains).

Comment: Very interesting example, thankyou! A couple of nitpicks: first, I think it really needs the universe as @MartinBrandenburg suggests, since Zorn’s Lemma doesn’t generally hold for proper class posets (consider $\mathrm{Ord}$, or $(V,\subseteq)$). Second, in the definition of $P$, how do you mean to define “no non-trivial relations hold”? I’d usually take that as referring to the syntax of the language, but here that would be begging the question. I guess instead you can take a “freeness” property in terms of mapping into models of the theory? (cont’d)

Comment: Finally, do you know anywhere this proof has appeared in the wild? — Especially in the literature, but if you’ve seen it taught in a course or heard it in folklore that would still be great to know! The question about free models of infinitary theories is certainly natural; and I could imagine something like this proof appearing in early universal algebra, perhaps (though I’m not sure how they’d handle my second nitpick above: my suggestion is a bit category-theories, but a category-theorist would usually prefer to do the whole proof using the obvious complete category instead of this poset).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I added an example not needing proper classes.  To answer your question about whether I've seen this sort of use of Zorn's lemma in a text, I have to answer no, but with good reason.  Zorn's lemma is really a combination of "well-order some underlying set" followed by "use transfinite induction to create the object you want", possibly using the well-ordering to pick elements in some sequence to build off of.  Many algebraists I know stop favoring Zorn's lemma later in their careers, in favor of explaining the underlying process.  (cont...)

Comment: Thus, the transfinite recursive constructions are the ones that usually appear in texts, not Zorn arguments.  But you could think of the recursion as an alternative version of Zorn's lemma, where we have pulled the use of AC (if needed) to the start of the process.  (The benefit being that sometimes we don't need AC, or posets, or chain; we just need to understand how to build the structure from the ground up.  And it is more amenable to inductive arguments)