Pedagogically intuitive reformulation of Zorn's Lemma for functional analysis
While teaching an applied functional analysis class, I’ve noticed that students often struggle to develop an intuitive understanding of Zorn’s lemma. It’s relatively straightforward to explain why traditional induction falls short in certain situations, but bridging the gap to the standard formulation of Zorn’s lemma can feel like a significant conceptual leap.
In functional analysis, the application of Zorn’s lemma frequently involves a final "assume for contradiction" step to ensure that the maximal element satisfies the desired properties. While this contradiction-based reasoning becomes routine with experience, it adds an additional layer of complexity that can be challenging for students.
This has led me to wonder: is there a more "pedagogically friendly" version of Zorn’s lemma? To clarify, such a version might follow a framework like this:

Define a partially ordered set $\mathcal{K}$.
Show that $\mathcal{K}$ is non-empty, analogous to the "base case" in induction.
From any $a \in \mathcal{K}$, construct a strictly larger element $b > a$ if $a$ does not satisfy a certain property $P(a)$, corresponding to the "induction step."
Conclude, via Zorn’s lemma, that there exists a maximal element in $\mathcal{K}$ that satisfies $P$.

A "pedagogical" version could integrate the standard requirement that every chain in $\mathcal{K}$ has an upper bound. In functional analysis, this condition is often addressed by forming unions, so perhaps this reasoning could be incorporated directly into a simplified framework.
I wouldn’t mind if this modified version of Zorn’s lemma is technically weaker than the traditional formulation, as long as it suffices for the common applications encountered in functional analysis.

See https://mathoverflow.net/a/436348/1946 for reasons why one might view Zorn's lemma, in its entirety, as a pedagogical substitute for transfinite recursion.

What about stating Zorn’s Lemma only for the case of partial orders of subsets of a given set ordered by inclusion?

https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15632 :-)

Part of the pedagogical problem might be that students expect the lemma to be easier than it is. Zorn's lemma is often said to be "equivalent to the axiom of choice", which might give the impression that it's just a trivial reformulation of the AC, when in fact deriving it requires some work.

As a logician myself, I have similar feelings to Joel in that I think transfinite induction and transfinite recursion are underappreciated as general techniques in mathematics.
That said it is possible to phrase common applications of Zorn's lemma as a kind of induction that doesn't explicitly reference ordinals. The formalism I'm going to lay out is more complicated than the ordinary presentation of Zorn's lemma, but I think it does actually capture what people are typically thinking in these proofs (and not just in the context of functional analysis). It also has the benefit of often avoiding the need for an explicit proof by contradiction, which people sometimes cite as a pedagogical issue.

Zornian Induction
The setup is that we have a poset $(P, \leq)$ of (potentially) partial solutions to a given problem and we have a set $C$ of conditions that we would like our solution to satisfy. There's some notion of a partial solution $p \in P$ satisfying a condition $c \in C$. (You could formalize this by actually specifying a binary relation between $P$ and $C$ or by thinking of elements of $C$ as literal subsets of $P$, but I prefer to just use words here.)
The 'principle of Zornian induction' says the following: If

satisfaction of conditions is monotonic (i.e., if $p$ satisfies $c$ and $p \leq q$, then $q$ satisfies $c$),
there is some partial solution (i.e., $P$ is non-empty),
any partial solution can be extended to satisfy any given condition (i.e., for any $p \in P$ and $c \in C$, there is a $q \geq p$ that satisfies $c$), and
chains of partial solutions can be extended to a partial solution (i.e., for any chain $X \subseteq P$, there is a $p \in P$ such that $p \geq q$ for all $q \in X$),

then there is a $p \in P$ that satisfies all $c \in C$.
This isn't the most parsimonious way of phrasing Zorn's lemma, as I already said, but typically there a conceptual difference between the argument for the last two bullet points. For instance, chains in $P$ often have a canonical least upper bound but the process of extending to satisfy a given condition usually involves an arbitrary choice. This framing also separates positive requirements, which are explicitly given in $C$, from negative requirements, which will typically be implicit in the definition of $P$.
Zornian induction is fairly easy to prove, so I'll give two proofs.
Proof using Zorn's lemma. The poset $(P,\leq)$ satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma, so it has a maximal element $p$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $p$ does not satisfy some $c \in C$. Then there is a $q \geq p$ that satisfies $c$, contradicting the fact that $p$ is maximal. Therefore no such $c$ can exist and $p$ satisfies every condition in $C$. $\square$
Proof using transfinite recursion. Let $(c_i)_{i < \alpha}$ be an enumeration of $C$. By assumption $P$ is non-empty, so let $p_0$ be some element of $P$ and define a sequence $(p_i)_{i \leq \alpha}$ by transfinite recursion. At stage $i$, given $p_i$, let $p_{i+1}$ be some partial solution $\geq p_i$ that satisfies $c_i$. At a limit stage $i$, we have that $(p_j)_{j < i}$ is a chain in $P$, so we can choose some $p_i$ that is $\geq p_j$ for every $j < i$. Finally by transfinite induction and monotonicity we have that $p_\alpha$ satisfies $c_i$ for each $i<\alpha$, but this is all of the conditions in $C$. $\square$
One thing to note is that the form of induction I've given is directly similar to how transfinite induction is often phrased (in terms of a base case for $0$, a successor case, and a limit case) and it's clear from the transfinite induction proof that this isn't an accident.

Example: The Hahn-Banach Theorem
I want to spell out an example of a proof phrased this way, but it will be pretty clear that the meat of the argument is the same as the ordinary Zorn's lemma proof.
Consider the Hahn-Banach theroem. Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $Y \subseteq X$ be a subspace. Let $f : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional with norm $1$.
Our partial order $P$ of partial solutions is the set of pairs $(Z,g)$, where $Z$ is a closed subspace of $X$ extending $Y$ and $g : Z \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional of norm $1$ that extends $f$. We have $(Z,g) \leq (Z',g')$ if $Z \subseteq Z'$ and $g'$ extends $g$.
Our set of conditions $C$ is $\{c_x : x \in X\}$ and what it means for a partial solutuion $(Z,g)$ to satisfy $c_x$ is just that $x \in Z$. This is because our ultimate goal is to build a total function on $X$. (We could also use $C = \{c_x : x \in X,~\lVert x \rVert = 1\}$. It wouldn't really make much of a difference.)
Clearly satisfaction is monotonic. Moreover we have that $(Y,f) \in P$, so $P$ is non-empty.
For the 'successor case,' fix $(Z,g) \in P$ and $x \in X$. If $x \in Z$, then we already have that $(Z,g) \geq (Z,g)$ satisfies $c_x$ as a condition (i.e., we don't need to do anything). Otherwise we have by the standard argument that there exists an extension $g'$ of $g$ to $Z+\mathbb{R}x$. Then $(Z+\mathbb{R}x,g') \geq (Z,g)$ is our extension satisfying the condition $c_x$.
For the 'limit case,' if we have a non-empty chain $H$ in $P$, then a fairly direct argument shows that $g = \bigcup\{h : (W,h) \in H\}$ is a linear operator defined on a dense subset of $Z = \overline{\bigcup\{W : (W,h) \in H\}}$ which moreover has norm $1$ and therefore has a unique norm $1$ extension $\overline{g}$ to $Z$, giving us our (canonical) partial solution $(Z,\overline{g})$ that is an upper bound of the chain $H$.
So, by Zornian induction, there is a $(Z,g) \in P$ that satisfies all of the conditions $c_x \in C$, but this precisely means that $g$ is a norm $1$ extension of $f$ to all of $X$.

Example: Existence of Prime Ideals
There's nothing about this framework that is particularly specialized to functional analysis. As such I think it would make sense to include an example from algebra. This is also a good example of a more complicated set of conditions.
Fix a non-trivial commutative ring $R$. Let $(P,\subseteq)$ be the poset of proper ideals of $R$ (i.e., ideals $I$ such that $1 \notin I$). Clearly $\{0\} \in P$, so our base case is covered.
Our set of conditions is $\{c_{a,b} : a,b \in R\}$, where $I$ satisfies $c_{a,b}$ if either

$ab$ is not in $I'$ for any $I' \supseteq I$ or
$a \in I$ or $b \in I$.

(As an aside, I should mention that this pattern of defining conditions in terms of either permanently avoiding a possible issue or solving an issue that has arisen is a really central idea in set-theoretic forcing and other related 'genericity' arguments in mathematical logic.)
Satisfaction of these conditions is monotonic by construction. I claim, moreover, that for any $a,b \in R$, any $I \in P$ has an extension $I' \supseteq I$ satisfying $c_{a,b}$. (This is also a relatively standard argument, which I'm adapting from this MSE answer.) If there is no $I' \supseteq I$ with $ab \in I'$, then we're done, so assume that there is an $I' \supseteq I$ in $P$ with $ab \in I'$ and fix some such $I'$. Consider the ideal $I'' =\langle I' \cup \{a\}\rangle$. If $1 \notin I''$, then we can take $I''$ our extension. Otherwise, there are $x \in I'$ and $r \in R$ such that $1 = x + ar$. This implies that $b = b1 = b(x+ar) = bx + bar$. But then $bx \in I'$ and $bar \in I'$, and so $bx + bar = b \in I'$ and $I'$ already satisfies $c_{a,b}$.
Unions of chains of ideals are obviously ideals. Moreover if every ideal in a chain does not contain $1$, then the union will not contain $1$ as well. Therefore we can apply Zornian induction and get an ideal $I \in P$ satisfying each $c_{a,b}$. This is exactly the same as saying that $I$ is a prime ideal, so we're done.

One thing to note is that this setup (a poset of partial solutions and a set of conditions that we would like a solution to satisfy) shows up all over the place in mathematical logic. Forcing in set theory, priority arguments in computability theory, back-and-forth and omitting types arguments in model theory, and a lot of diagonalization arguments all use this idea. It shows up outside of logic too, such as in the proof of the Baire category theorem.

Side remark: in the Hahn-Banach example you don't need $Z$ to be closed, which simplifies the limit case a bit.

Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll definitely use it the next time I have to teach functional analysis and then report back how it went ;-)
